# Residue theorem to solve improper integrals

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, several-complex-variables

[image]

This is an example of using the residue theorem to solve improper integrals. My question is how the πi term came about, because my understanding is $\int_{C{_R}}1/z dz=2 πi$ and not πi. Sorry I must be missing something simple here

Answer (score 2):

$\Gamma_R$ is surely a *semi*-circle, so we just pick up $i\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, does the fact that C is a upper semi circle also explain why RHS only contain the plus sign when the term preceding it has two minus signs?

Comment: If we used the lower semi-circle we'd have to go backwards round it, but we'll eventually get the same answer.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If we close in the lower-half plane, the integral $\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz$ does not approach $0$ as $R\to \infty$.  So, we would need to replace $e^{iz}$ with $e^{-iz}$, close in the lower-half plane, and proceed.

Comment: Ahh nice observations indeed thanks, I just posted another question I'm having in a related field as well ><

Comment: @Dr.MV, you are absolutely right, but that comes later than the question as set! But I do think that in these questions people sometimes forget that a solution needs a clear statement of the integrand [the important detail of defn at 0 and why analytic are suppressed here], of the contour [we have to guess here], why Cauchy/Res Thm applies, calculation of residues, and then analysis of what happens as $R$ or whatever tends to infinity [ignored here].

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac1z\,dz&=\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\pi i
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, does the fact that C is a upper semi circle also explain why RHS only contain the plus sign when the term preceding it has two minus signs?

Comment: We cannot close in the lower-half plane and still expect to have $$\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\to 0$$So, if we want to close in the lower-half plane, we would start with $e^{-iz}$ (instead of $e^{iz}$), and proceed.  Of course, the final result is the same.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark